# PHP $_POST Associative Array Returns null

Tags: php, forms, associative-array

Input values

```
    <input type="hidden" name="service_row[1]['row']" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="service_row[1]['check']" />
    <input type="text" name="service_row[1]['observation']" />
    <input type="text" name="service_row[1]['parts']" />
```

Handler code

```
    foreach ($_POST['service_row'] as $data) {
        $row_num = $data['row'];
        if (isset($data['check'])) {
            $checked = 1;
        } else {
            $checked = 0;
        }
        $observation = database::escape($data['observation']);
        $parts = database::escape($data['parts']);
    }
```

My var dump on $data displays

```
    array
       ''row'' => string '1' (length=1)
       ''observation'' => string 'Test' (length=4)
       ''parts'' => string 'Test' (length=4)
```

So from what I can see is that the $data array exists and displays the values I have put in but for some reason when I try to put the data into a variable it returns null.

Can anyone see what I am not seeing here? Any help is much appreciated, this one got me stumped right now.

Comment: What is `database::escape()` doing? Is it returning correctly?

Comment: In your HTML form, remove the quotes from the array keys. `service[1][row]` etc...

Comment: @SnapGravy Be sure to mark Alexander's answer accepted below by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you must use index `'row'` instead of `row` or remove quotes from your html.

Comment: Removing the quotes fixed the issue.
Thanks to Alexander and Michael for your quick response. Easy to go blind once in a while :D